# How to dynamically change URL without reloading?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

OK, this what I'm trying to do (I think Google mostly does this as well) :

**Scenario A :**

In page `/Main_Page` let's say there are 3 sections. When user clicks on section A "link", `section A`'s content is loaded through AJAX and embedded into the page.

**Scenario B :**

When `/Main_Page/Section_A` is loaded, we practically go to the very same page (as in scenario A) - `/Main_Page` and load `Section A` via AJAX - as before.

---

**The problem :**

We've got 2 identical resulting pages, but the URL is different (in the first case it'll be just `/Main_Page`, while in the second it will be `/Main_Page/Section_A`).

**What I want to do :**

- In Scenario A, after loading `Section A` via AJAX, how should I do it so that the appearing URL (in the browser address bar) is `/Main_Page/Section_A` (or anything else for that matter), without any sort of redirecting, page reloading, etc?

Comment: You're looking for [History API](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html), here's a [demo](http://html5demos.com/history/)

Comment: Maybe you are looking for hash tags in URLs (like https://twitter.com/#!/search-home). Google has a nice tutorial how to crawl these pages: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174992

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Your problem can be solved by implementing the [History API](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#the-history-interface), especially by using the [`pushState()`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#dom-history-pushstate) method. I recommend [reading about it in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). There's also an all-in-one solution called [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js), it will help you implement it x-browser easily (It will fallback to URL hashes `#` if the browser doesn't support it).

Here's an example:

```
history.pushState('', 'New Page Title', newHREF);
```

Not excited enough? Here's a [demo](http://html5doctor.com/demos/history/) that will encourage you to implement it.

Comment: This definitely seems promising; I've already started studying it and it's most likely what I'll be using (the `history.js` approach seems more `viable` to get it working fast). Thanks a lot, buddy! :-)

Comment: As a follow-up, just to let you know : It's working brilliantly! :-)

Comment: @Jleagle True. But the example given regarding `history.js` works like a charm - so, basically no need for any other example. ;-)

Comment: @Jleagle, you're right :) Thanks for letting me know, I've updated the link with a different one.

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon, thanks for the follow-up. It's very nice to see question posters like you. Clear question, appreciation (not necessarily upvote/accept), follow-up.

Comment: @Adnan I'm a frequent answerer myself (and in love with coding, as much as one could be), so I do know what you mean : this whole interaction is one of the things I adore about StackOverflow, making it one of the most valuable communities/resources for programmmers. Cheers!

Comment: Does this thing work on IE?

Comment: @user1200125 History API isn't supported by IE until IE10. History.js, however, seamlessly reverts to the old `onhashchange`.

Comment: Tell me how you did that stuff with the smiley in your profile XD

Answer (score 9):

I just found a tutorial and it worked for me,

```
$('a').click(function(){
var value = $(this).attr('id');
window.location.hash = value; // it appends id to url without refresh
});


$(window).bind('hashchange' function() {
    var newhash = window.location.hash.substring(1) // it gets id of clicked element
    // use load function of jquery to do the necessary...
});
```

i got the above code from 
http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/85-best-practices-dynamic-content/